# Maximum likelihood estimation for state space models using BFGS

Tags: optimization, kalman-filter

I have written some code that can do Kalman filtering (using a number of different Kalman-type filters [Information Filter et al.]) for Linear Gaussian State Space Analysis for an n-dimensional state vector.

Let us consider the linear Gaussian State Space model

$$y_t = \mathbf{Z}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \epsilon_{t},$$
$$\alpha_{t + 1} = \mathbf{T}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \mathbf{R}_{t}\eta_{t},$$

where $y_{t}$ is our observation vector, $\alpha_{t}$ our state vector at time step $t$. The quantities in bold are the transformation matrices of the state space model which are set according to the characteristics of the system under consideration. We also have

$$\epsilon_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{H}_{t}),$$
$$\eta_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{Q}_{t}),$$
$$\alpha_{1} \sim NID(a_{1}, \mathbf{P}_{1}).$$

where $t = 1,\ldots, n$. Now, I have derived and implemented the recursion for the Kalman Filter for this generic state space model by guessing the initial parameters and variance matrices $\mathbf{H}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{1}$.

where the points are the Nile River water levels for Jan over 100 years, the line is the Kalamn Estimated state, and the dashed lines are the 90% confidence levels.

Now, in order to estimate the initial parameters of my model ($\mathbf{H}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{1}$) I have adopted the Expectation Maximisation method to maximise the loglikelihood function

$$\log L(Y_{n}|\psi) = -\frac{np}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{t = 1}(log|\mathbf{F}_{t}| + v^{\mathsf{T}}_{t}\mathbf{F}_{t}^{-1}v_{t}), \;\;\;\; (1)$$

with respect to parameter vector $\psi$. Where $v_{t}$ is the state error and $\mathbf{F}_{t}$ is the state error variance. The vector $\psi$ contains the unknown parameters (i.e., either the measurement and state disturbance variances themselves, or a re-parametrisation of these same variances, see below)

A crucial role in the maximisation of (1) is played by the gradient or score vector

$$\partial_{1}(\psi) = \partial \log L(Y_{n}|\psi)/\partial\psi,\;\;\;\; (2)$$

At least two algorithms can be used to maximise (1). The first is the so-called EM (Expectation-Maximisation) algorithm, and the second is the BFGS (Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno) algorithm. I have successfully implemented the EM algorithm and this is providing correct results but is very slow; in light of this I now wish to implement the BFGS algorithm as this has better performance.

So, from (2) using Taylor's theorem we can write

$$\partial_{1}(\psi) \simeq \tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi) + \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)(\psi - \tilde{\psi}),$$

where $\partial_{2}(\psi)$ is the Hessian matrix or second derivative of the loglikelihood function wrt $\psi$ and $\tilde{\partial}_{N}(\psi) = \partial_{N}(\psi)|_{\psi = \tilde{\psi}}$. So now we can write our updated parameter vector as

$$\bar{\psi} = \tilde{\psi} - \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)^{-1}\tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi) = \tilde{\psi} - s\tilde{\pi(\psi)}.\;\;\;\; (3)$$

where here $\tilde{\pi(\psi)} = - \tilde{\partial}_{2}(\psi)^{-1}\tilde{\partial}_{1}(\psi)$ and $s$ is our step size. So the basic outline of the BFGS algorithm to get our parameter vector and maximize (1) using BFGS is:

1. Initialise parameter vector $\psi = \psi^{*}$.
2. Then apply the Kalman and disturbance smoothing filters and thus for score vector (2) at $\psi = \psi^{*}$. When running the Kalman Filter evaluate the log-likelihood function.
3. Use (3) to obtain new values for $\psi$ given by $\psi^{+}$ and go back to step 2 until the value of loglikelihood function (1) no longer improves.

This seems fine, but my problem is how to calculate the step size $s$ in (3) above. I know a line search is required, but remember $\psi$ is a vector and it is not clear what function I can use in a traditional line search technique in order to evaluate $s$.

**Question: what line search method should I use in order to evaluate $s$?**

---

Ps. Assume that I would like to use the zoom line search algorithm (algorithm 3.5 of [Numerical Optimization by Nocedal & Wright](http://faculty.bracu.ac.bd/~faruqe/books/numericalanalysis/Numerical%20Optimization%202ed.pdf)).

Comment: Cross posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837907/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-state-space-models-using-bfgs

Comment: I have remove the Math one now.

Comment: Not sure, just letting the mods know so they can decide.

Comment: Do you have an answer for me :]

Comment: No, sadly this is way outside my area of expertise :{

Comment: You'd be better off asking at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ Sorry to have to move you again :)

Comment: Is your specific goal to use BFGS, and write it yourself? Otherwise there are a number of numerical computer packages that will optimize the likelihood of a linear Gaussian state space model quite well. One is ADMB, link [here](http://admb-project.org/)

Comment: Yes, I want to write this all from scratch. I have the EM algorithm working for parameter estimation for N-dimensional parameter vectors, but this _can_ be slow. I here (L-)BFGS is fast, but it is not clear how to get the step size $s$ from the line search in the above case... Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The "S" in BFGS is ***Shanno***, not *Shannon*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will give you an answer from my experience developing the R package 
[stsm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=stsm) that is introduced in [this document](http://www.jalobe.com:8080/doc/stsm.pdf). By default ithe package uses the function `optimize`, which is a combination of a golden section search and successive parabolic interpolation. Other line search algorithms, such as the zoom line search algorithm will do the job similarly well. The algorithm in function `optimize` is convenient because it does not require the gradient of the function to be minimized. Here is some pseudo code to compute the optimal step size:

```
fcn.step <- function(step, model, direction)
{
  trial.pars <- model$pars + step * direction
  -logLik(model, pars = trial.pars)
}
s <- line.search(f = fcn.step, interval = c(0, 1))
```

`fcn.step` is the function to be minimized, the only parameter is the step size; the parameters of the model are fixed to the values from the last iteration of the BFGS optimization algorithm. The negative of the log-likelihood function is minimized with respect to the step size; `direction` is the optimal direction vector computed at the current iteration of the BFGS algorithm, $\tilde{\pi(\psi)}$ in your notation.

It is also important the choice of the upper limit of the interval where the 
optimal value of the step size `s` is searched. By default, the package `stsm` calculates the maximum value of `s` that is compatible with positive values for the variance parameters updated in equation (3). If this value is lower than $1$ then it is taken as the upper bound passed to the line search algorithm, otherwise this bound is set equal to $1$. You may look at function `step.maxsize` in the package or the function `calc.constraint` in [this implementation](http://economics.sas.upenn.edu/~clausen/computing/optim.php) of the BFGS algorithm.

With this approach you can apply the BFGS algorithm without the risk of reaching a local optimum with negative variance parameters. Otherwise, 
I would recommend you either the [L-BFGS-B algorithm](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0916069), which allows setting a lower bound equal to zero in the parameter space where the algorithm searches for the optimum; or a reparameterization of the model, e.g. `variance = theta^2` or `variance = exp(theta)` and maximize the likelihood with respect to `theta`.

As regards the EM algorithm, as you mention, it is slow to converge. Strangely enough, it converges slower as it approaches the local optimum. For some insight into this issue and a modified EM algorithm you may look at [this document](http://www.jalobe.com:8080/doc/stsm-em.pdf). I am the author of this document, you may send me an e-mail if you have any questions about it or if you want a copy (the link is not always available).

Optimization of the likelihood function of state space models can be hard in practice. Some enhancements to the general-purpose optimization algorithm are recommended. For example, one of the parameters of the model can be concentrated out of the likelihood function; maximum likelihood in the frequency domain enjoys some advantages from a computational point of view and may provide good values to be used as starting values in the optimization of the time domain likelihood function.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I have recently gone back to this problem having solved it by using a very basic Newtonian Line Search. I have since read your paper on the modified EM algorithm and it is a really neat formulation, which I may look to implement in the future.